# Spring Security: /logout url is caught by an other Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hello I have a Controller method with the mapping `@RequestMapping(value = "/{barUrlName}")`

I need it this way to keep nice URLS

however when i try to logout with /logout, which should be managed by Spring Security, it is catched by this mapping.

Is there a way to make Spring Security waking up first? 
My other idea was to create an other method in my Controller mapped on /logout but I dont know how to logout manually in this method...

Thank you!

**Edit: Solution**

As mentionned by Branislav Lazic and Serge Ballesta, I add to change the logoutUrl. Which in Java configuration give :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
         //CSRF enable
        //.csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        [...]
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and()
        .logout()
        //with csrf you need to configure logoutRequestMatcher instead of logoutUrl if it is disable
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/app/logout"));
}
```

Comment: Just change your logout success url in security context `xml` and you should be fine. To something like: `/app/logout`

Comment: If you configure correctly `logout url="..."` in security context, it should work fine because Spring security uses filters that are processed before controllers.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I add a last issue with csrf stuff but it s OK now